# Grails and Spring security: password is invalid after some time?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm trying to migrate old Grails app from `AppFog` to `Linode` servers. I migrated code and MYSQL database, but I couldn't log in with old credentials.

For some reason, I suspected that I forgot password so I simply deleted my user directly from the database and let `Bootstrap.groovy` creates a new one with known password so I managed to log in again.

Next day, when I tried to log in again, I received `wrong credentials` message so I looked at the database and verified that hashed password is still the same. I repeat **delete user and Bootstrap** procedure and noticed that password hash is different than the previous one for the same password.

Again, I managed to log in through GUI and even (via GUI) update password for other users (user from `Bootstrap.groovy` have admin role). I verified that all password hashes were updated in databases and I verified each account login via GUI, everything was fine.

This morning, when I tried to log into the application I was rejected again on several accounts that I verified last night.

The only thing that I noticed that is different is the format of hashed password: previously it was a sequence of chars and numbers but now it always starts with `$2a$` and containing special characters.

I noticed few forums and SO post mentioning that using `spring-security-gui` could cause double hashing of passwords but I'm not using that plugin.

Here is the list of (relevant) plugins that I'm using:

- tomcat:7.0.52.1
- hibernate:3.6.10.9
- database-migration:1.3.8"
- spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"

I just noticed that the old version of app was using `spring-security-core:1.2.7.3` and latest one is using `2.0-RC4` (I updated some out-dated plugins before migration)

UPDATE:
Unfortunatelly, problem is still active. I bootstraped user and verify that password is hashed in 'sha format'. I can log in with that user and change passwords of other users. I verified that all passwords are sha hashed in database. I can log with each user that I resetted password including bootstraped one. After one day (aproximately) I can not log again with previously used credentails on any user. I checked database and password hashes are same as before. Nothing in tomcat, mysql or syslog logs. Same application was running on AppFog for more that one year without restart and no problems were noticed. I'm not 100% sure what spring security plugin version was used at AppFog site (legacy maintenance) but, only thing that is changed is version of that plugin (if it wasnt used before). There are no background jobs that can trigger this behavior (e.g. user.save() calls) so I don't have a clue what could go wrong or what else I need to set.

Comment: related to "after some time" - most likely you have `user.save()` somewhere, msot likely on user auth, which replaces existing hash with new one

Answer (score 1):

Set the following two properties in your `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = "SHA-256"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1
```

That will also allow you to log in with the old password. Spring Security 1.x uses the `SHA-256` but the new Spring Security 2.x uses now `bcrypt` algorithms.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/newInV2.html

Comment: Thx a lot, that worked! Still, I'm curious  what coused this situation that password became invalid after some time...

Comment: Is there any job running which is updating the user instance? Also, can you please show me your User domain

Comment: There are no backgroud jobs at all so, nothing on that side. Regarding my user domain, beside basic properties and constrains, here are only three methods (sorry, don't know how to format comment):  def beforeInsert() {
  encodePassword()
 }

 def beforeUpdate() {
  if (isDirty('password')) {
   encodePassword()
  }
 }

 protected void encodePassword() {
  password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
 }

Comment: sorry for rejecting aswer but actual problem is still active (regardless of that your tip helped me with password hashing)